# EMR AWS increase number of mappers

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, emr

I am executing a mapreduce program on AWS and the code is working correctly.
My problem is with the number of map functions that work in parallel.
every time I execute the program, there is only one map function and only one node working in parallel.

my input file contains 100 line with a size of 4 kB. I need to make a map function for each 20 lines that run in parallel.

I tried to change "fs.s3n.block.size" parameter in the config yet nothing has changed.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of file is it? Is it a splittable file type?

Comment: text file. I don't know what you mean with splittable file. but when I run it on eclipse each line executes a map function.

Comment: The problem is solved, you just need to set the attribute 'mapred.max.split.size' in the config at a smaller value so it splits the file on different machines.
# conf.setInt("mapred.max.split.size",512);